# Can we create something like a temperal invisibilty cloak by phasing molecules?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, molecules

I am only just 14 years old and i am interested in this subject. Can you pls help me with it.thank you.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by phasing molecules? Can you post a bit more on that, or where you read about it.

Comment: BY phasing molecules i mean that can molecules be shifted into a state where they are invisible

Comment: Where have you read about this? Please identify where your ideas are coming from.

Comment: Sounds like Star Trek techno-babble.

Comment: No. It is impossible on the current technology, some similar already exist in experimental level but a real invisibility cloak seems currently impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In science fiction, there is a common plot device where someone can 'phase' away from interacting with ordinary matter.

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Intangibility?from=Main.IntangibleMan

Although this is a very intriguing idea, the only thing I've seen in the reading scientific papers that is even close to this idea is some speculative work on dark matter.

A few physicists ([Robert Foot](https://findanexpert.unimelb.edu.au/display/person14116) is one of the most commonly seen) like the an idea called [Mirror Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_matter).  In the Mirror Matter hypothesis, dark matter is a copy of ordinary matter, but is invisible because it has it's own exclusive photons that interact just with mirror matter, but not with ordinary matter (and vice versa).

If true, mirror matter could also pass through ordinary matter pretty easily since the interactions that normally keep things from passing through each other wouldn't apply.  The only thing these matter and mirror matter interact by is gravity (and maybe the Higgs...)

This as close as I've seen the common sci-fi idea of intangibility/invisibility, but here's the thing: even if the mirror matter idea was verified, it still is wouldn't mean that we could turn things from matter to mirror matter and back.

And let me say this again: while the mirror matter idea is fun to think about, it has yet to be verified an a definitive way.

Comment: Dark matter, damn it......:)

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways of making things invisible:

1. The first method is listed here, and is the one your question is really about:

[How to make an object invisible](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/407677/how-to-make-an-object-invisible/)

> To become invisible, an object must do two things: it has to be able to bend light around itself, so that it casts no shadow, and it must produce no reflection. While naturally occurring materials are unable to do this, a new class of materials called metamaterials is now making it possible.

[image]

> Bending light around an object requires a material to have a negative refractive index. The refractive index is a property that dictates how light passes through a medium; it’s the reason a stick will look bent when placed in water. If water had a negative refractive index, it would make the stick look as though it were bending back on itself.

2. The next method is by changing the refractive index. If you watch this video [An Invisible testube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIovk_LgHRA) you can find out how the refractive index is important in becoming invisible.
3. Camouflage is used by many animals, especially marine creatures. They can shift the colors of their skin to match the seafloor color and it can be very difficult to see them, as their bodies are reflecting almost the same frequencies of light energy as the sand or stones around then.

[image]

Image Source and Video: [Hidden Octopus](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/earth/wildlife/11389875/This-octopus-has-some-serious-camouflage-skills.html)

Can you see the octopus?

4.If it is nighttime,  turn off the light in your room. So now no reflection of the chair or whatever comes back off of the object and into your eyes. It's invisible because we have not supplied the molecules of a chair say, with energy, in the form of light,  so the molecules of the chair cannot vibrate and are not able to produce energy. This  might be  the nearest to what you ask when you say:

> molecules be shifted into a state where they are invisible.

It is very straightforward, in one way, we just take for granted that you won't see things by turning of the light, but you need to ask yourself why this happens. By not giving them energy, they are in a state in which they are invisible.